# Pygame ImportError in python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, pip

I tried Importing Pygame in python 3 and it outputs `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`, so I checked `pip` if I had installed it or not so run `pip install pygame` and it outputs `Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` so I guess 2 questions popped!

**My question**

1. Is pygame installed here only for python2.7?
2. How do I install it for python3 or higher?

Additional Information :

I had made a pygame program before but didn't realized that it was in python 2.7, and when I tried to run it, it outputs `ImportError : No module named 'pygame'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the pip version

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: I did not know there was a pip3 *facepalm*